# How to call a function when user leaves a textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, dom

I'm not sure if I made the title clear or not but I am doing some form validation and I want a function to be called when the user unfocuses from the textbox. While the user is in the textbox, the instructions will be shown but once the user moves on to the next textbox I want a function to be called so that it will check whether the user inputted data to the specifications or not or at all (so for the first name input box, I want it to validate whether or not the user entered only letters and the function will be called in real-time as soon as the user moves away from the textbox and on to the last name text box).

```js
function validate() {
  var alpha = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname");
  if (firstName == alpha) {
    alert("Yes")
  } else {
    alert("No")
  }
}
```

```css
#prompt {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 30px;
  visibly: hidden;
}
#prompt2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 30px;
  visibly: hidden;
}
.input:focus+#prompt {
  color: #000;
  visibily: visible;
}
.input:focus+#prompt2 {
  color: #000;
  visibily: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.cs">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/process_form.js"></script>
    <title>Survey - Zhi Lin</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend> Personal</legend>

        First Name: <br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="input">
        <span id="prompt">Please enter first name</span>
        <br>
        Last Name: <br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="input">
        <span id="prompt2">Please enter last name</span>
        <br>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use jQuery**

```
$('input[name ="firstname"]')).focusout(function(){
   var alpha = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname");
  if (firstName == alpha) {
    alert("Yes")
  } else {
    alert("No")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just fire the "onchange" event.
Just need to do -

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="input" onchange="validate()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate() {
    alert("function validate calling")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="input" onfocusout="validate()">
```

you can call your function using onfocusout event:

**The focusout** event occurs when an element (or any elements inside it) loses focus.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="input" onfocusout="validate()">
```

Comment: hmm it doesn't seem to be working even after adding that event my test alerts doesn't show up when I put type into the textboxes and switch to the lastname textbox @Chirag

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "blur" or "focusout" event listener to your input element.

```js
function validate() {
  var alpha = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0]; // Get first element
  if (alpha.test(firstName)) {
    alert("Yes")
  } else {
    alert("No")
  }
}

document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur', validate);
```

Note also that, when you use "getElementsByName" to select the input element, you get an array of elements, so, in this case, you'll have to get the first element of the array.